# Compute the discriminant and the conductor of an elliptic curve using magma

Tags: elliptic-curves, magma-cas

To compute the minimal discriminant and the conductor of an elliptic curve using Magma, for example this elliptic curve, we use this command

`E:=EllipticCurve([0,8,0,48,0]);
E;
F:=MinimalModel(E);
F;
D:=Discriminant(F);
N:=Conductor(E);`

My question is how we can compute the discriminant and the conductor when the curve has coefficient  are variable for example this elliptic curve

$ y^2=x(x-a)(x-D^{p}\zeta_{k}) $
Where $a , D $ are integers and $\zeta_{k} $ is the $k$th root of unity.

Comment: You want this for general values of $a$, $D$, and $k$? If so, I don't think this can be computed in Magma. For one thing, then your really defining an elliptic curve over $\mathbb{Z}[\zeta][a, D]$, so there is no notion of a minimal model. Similarly, I think the conductor is computed using something like Tate's algorithm, which only works when the based ring localized at each prime is a DVR. If you choose particular values for $k, a, D$ (and what is $p$?) then it should be possible.

Comment: $D$ is congruence 1. Modulo 4 , $p$ is prime greater than $5$ and $a$ is even and $k=4$

Comment: You need **particular** values for $k$, $a$, $D$, and $p$. Magma isn't really intended to solve a symbolic problem like this in terms of your variables.

Comment: You can compute the discriminant of a given model by defining the curve over $K = \mathbb{Q}(\zeta, a, D)$ via
K<z, a, D> := FunctionField(Rationals(), 3);
R<x> := PolynomialRing(K);
E := EllipticCurve(x*(x-a)*(x - D*z));
Discriminant(E);

Of course this will not give you the full picture if you are looking for the minimal discriminant, similarly it will not give you the conductor.